# From Java, capture mouse click and use as hotkey?

Tags: java, input, mouse, hotkeys

For keyboard, I'm using this to capture keyboard inputs: JIntellitype

This works extremely well, but I would also like to capture mouse events (clicks specifically) and use them as global "hotkeys".

Platform is Windows only, language is Java.  I would prefer a nice Java package, and hopefully avoid using JNI/JNA calls or Win32 directly (those are fine though if they are in a nice wrapper).

Comment: How do you use mouse events as a hot key? Also it seems as if you want a global mouse listener, and Java may not be the best tool for this. Instead since this is a Windows app, I recommend that you give a try to [AutoIt v3](http://www.autoitscript.com/site/).

Comment: To answer your first question.  Say I left click in notepad, it brings up a menu. But say I want a hotkey on my left click.  I left click, it brings up menu and maco kicks in that auto scrolls down and selects 'paste'.  That's a simple example, but lots of potential there.  In regards to autoit, we use it; but it's cumbersome at best.  In regards to other languages, yes you are probably correct; there are probably better languages for this, but I have a lot of existing libraries that I want to use and also my preferred language.

Comment: I agree that AutoIt is cumbersome and terrible for creating GUI's, but it's great for creating very small utilities, and I've had some decent success calling these utilities from my Java GUI's.

Comment: Definitely do-able with JNA, can't think of an easier way.  I've done something similar with JNA, using the 4th/5th mouse buttons as global shortcut keys.  Wasn't too bad, took about 150-200 lines of Java code.

Comment: @prunge, do you perhaps have any code that you could share?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use JNA, you can use something similar to the following code.

Using JNA 3.3.0 and JNA platform JAR.

More doco on the LowLevelMouseProc function [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644986%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and the mouse events [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff468877%28v=VS.85%29.aspx).

MouseHook.java:

```
package jnatest;

import jnatest.WinUserX.LowLevelMouseProc;
import jnatest.WinUserX.MSLLHOOKSTRUCT;

import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.Kernel32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.User32;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.HMODULE;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.HHOOK;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser.MSG;

public class MouseHook
{
    private static volatile boolean quit;
    private static HHOOK hhk;
    private static LowLevelMouseProc mouseHook;

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Press middle button to quit.");
        final User32 lib = User32.INSTANCE;
        HMODULE hMod = Kernel32.INSTANCE.GetModuleHandle(null);
        mouseHook = new LowLevelMouseProc() 
        {
            public LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, MSLLHOOKSTRUCT info) 
            {
                if (nCode >= 0) 
                {
                    switch (wParam.intValue())
                    {
                        case WinUserX.WM_LBUTTONDOWN:
                            System.out.println("Left button click at " + info.pt.x + ", " + info.pt.y);
                            break;
                        case WinUserX.WM_LBUTTONUP:
                            System.out.println("Left button release.");
                            break;
                        case WinUserX.WM_MBUTTONDOWN:
                            System.out.println("Middle button.");
                            quit = true;
                            break;
                    }
                }
                return lib.CallNextHookEx(hhk, nCode, wParam, info.getPointer());
            }
        };
        hhk = lib.SetWindowsHookEx(WinUser.WH_MOUSE_LL, mouseHook, hMod, 0);
        new Thread() 
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                while (!quit) 
                {
                    try { Thread.sleep(10); } catch(InterruptedException e) { }
                }
                System.err.println("unhook and exit");
                lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
                System.exit(0);
            }
        }.start();

        // This bit never returns from GetMessage
        int result;
        MSG msg = new MSG();
        while ((result = lib.GetMessage(msg, null, 0, 0)) != 0) 
        {
            if (result == -1) 
            {
                System.err.println("error in get message");
                break;
            }
            else 
            {
                System.err.println("got message");
                lib.TranslateMessage(msg);
                lib.DispatchMessage(msg);
            }
        }
        lib.UnhookWindowsHookEx(hhk);
    }
}
```

WinUserX.java:

```
package jnatest;

import com.sun.jna.Structure;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.BaseTSD.ULONG_PTR;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.LRESULT;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinDef.WPARAM;
import com.sun.jna.platform.win32.WinUser;

public interface WinUserX extends WinUser
{
    public int WM_LBUTTONDOWN = 0x0201;
    public int WM_LBUTTONUP = 0x0202; 
    public int WM_MOUSEMOVE = 0x0200;
    public int WM_MOUSEWHEEL = 0x020A;
    public int WM_MOUSEHWHEEL = 0x020E;
    public int WM_RBUTTONDOWN = 0x0204;
    public int WM_RBUTTONUP = 0x0205;
    public int WM_MBUTTONDOWN = 0x0207;

    public interface LowLevelMouseProc extends HOOKPROC 
    {
        LRESULT callback(int nCode, WPARAM wParam, MSLLHOOKSTRUCT lParam);
    }

    public class MSLLHOOKSTRUCT extends Structure 
    {
        public POINT pt;
        public int mouseData;
        public int flags;
        public int time;
        public ULONG_PTR dwExtraInfo;
    }
}
```